# How can I access a value in an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this which I console log like this:

```
console.log(node.data.target.fields);
```

```
file:
en-US: {url: "//images.ctfassets.net/qkwv5aiilkmk/4YsaPFrSxMPKuMVnO/efb6b59a369e4f30105aaea54fb9f62f/aaa.jpeg", details: {…}, fileName: "aaa.jpeg", contentType: "image/jpeg"}
```

I want to access the url value but It throws an error :

```
const url = node.data.target.fields.file.['en-US'].url;
```

How can I access the en-Us variable properly?

Comment: `file.['en-US'].url`  looks like a simple typo,  did you mean to do `file['en-US'].url`  IOW: you put an extra dot in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `en-US` cannot be used as a variable name (`-` is an operator, cannot be used as a part of a variable), you cannot use the dot notation. So the only way you can access is using the `[]` notation.

```
const url = node.data.target.fields.file['en-US'].url;
```

The above is the right way of accessing it, else, you can also access this way:

```
const lang = 'en-US';
const url = node.data.target.fields.file[lang].url;
```

Two cases example:

```js
const node = {
  data: {
    target: {
      fields: {
        file: {
          "en-US": {
            url: "//images.ctfassets.net/qkwv5aiilkmk/"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

(() => {
  console.log("Using direct access...");
  const url = node.data.target.fields.file['en-US'].url;
  console.log(url);
})();

(() => {
  console.log("Using a variable...");
  const lang = 'en-US';
  const url = node.data.target.fields.file[lang].url;
  console.log(url);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add from the given answer just a few guidelines for accessing Object Properties here are some tips that would help you in the future.

**1. Dot property accessor**

This common way to access the property of an object is the dot property accessor syntax:
`expression.identifier`

```
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Dot property accessor
hero.name; // => 'Batman'
```

**1.1 Dot property accessor requires identifiers**

-The dot property accessor works correctly when the property name is a valid identifier. An identifier in JavaScript contains Unicode letters, $, _, and digits 0..9, but cannot start with a digit.

```
const weirdObject = {
  'prop-3': 'three',
  '3': 'three'
};

weirdObject.prop-3; // => NaN
weirdObject.3;     // throws SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

- To access the properties with these special names, use the square brackets property accessor (which is described in the next section):

```
const weirdObject = {
  'prop-3': 'three',
  '3': 'three'
};

weirdObject['prop-3']; // => 'three'
weirdObject[3];        // => 'three'
```

**2. Square brackets property accessor:**

-expression[expression]

```
const property = 'name';
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Square brackets property accessor:
hero['name'];   // => 'Batman'
hero[property]; // => 'Batman'
```

**3. Object destructuring:**

- const { identifier } = expression;

```
const hero = {
  name: 'Batman'
};

// Object destructuring:
const { name } = hero;name; // => 'Batman'
```

**Note that you can extract as many properties as you’d like:**
**const { identifier1, identifier2, .., identifierN } = expression;**